# Evaluating function

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, nested-radicals

Here is the function:

$$f(a)=\sqrt{f(a)+\sqrt{f(f(a))+\sqrt{f(f(f(a)))+\cdots}}}$$
Is there another way to represent this function so that it only has $f(a)$ on one side and no $f(a)$'s on the other side of the $=$ sign? In other words, simplify the function as best as you can. Thank you very much.

Comment: Certainly not without some information on $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square both sides, rearrange and simplify:

$f(a) \cdot (f(a) - 1) - f(f(a)) = 0$

I doubt there is any way to get rid of the $f(f(a))$ term.  And it may introduce extraneous solutions because of the squaring.

Comment: So, $ f(a)=a^2-a $

Comment: @YogUrt How do you exclude the possibility of other solutions?

Comment: Extraneous solutions because of the squaring is not the only problem -- one also needs the infinite nested radical to converge in the first place. If we take $f(a)=a^2-a$ as @Yog suggests, it seems like half of the convergents will have an imaginary square root in the innermost position, and then we end with a question of which branch of the square root function to choose.

Comment: @ A.P. They are possible: for example $ f(a) \equiv 0 $

Comment: @A.P.: We would need to have $f(x)=x(x-1)$ for at least all $x$ in the range of $f$. But the range can be chosen small -- for example the constant functions $f(a)=2$ and $f(a)=0$ are both solutions.

Comment: We certainly don't have $f(a)=a^2-a$ when $0<a<1$

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Yes. Exampes: $ f_1(a) \equiv 0, f_2(a) = 0 $ for $ a<1, $ and $ f_2(a)= a(a-1) $ for $ a>1, f_3(a) \equiv 2 $ etc.